# Помощь сделать маску телефона на jquery

Tags: jquery, mask

Вечер добрый, помогите с маской

```
<script src="js/jquery.mask.min.js "></script>

$("#phone_popup").mask("+38(999)999-99-99")
```

На выходе когда делаю `$(this).serialize()` получаю номер в формате 9999999999, как сделать что бы 38 не обрезало?

Answer (score 0):

ваш пример работает нормально

```
var vv = $("#phone_popup").mask("+38(999)999-99-99");

$( ".btn" ).click(function() {
  console.log(vv.val())
});
```

[пример на jsfidle](https://jsfiddle.net/KLON/toez8g4c/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вы как-то неправильно сериализируете форму, я попробовал воспроизвести ваш пример, и у меня `+38` не обрезается

```js
$("#phone_popup").mask("+38(999)999-99-99");
$('button').on('click', function () {
  console.log($('form').serialize());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="phone_popup" name="phone"/>
</form>

<button>Serialize</button>
```